# Can a multi-threaded Python app change the CWD?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, thread-safety, race-condition

Would the `assert` statement in this code raise an error under any Python 3.11+ interpreter?

Can the current working directory be changed by another module without this code using any `async` features?

```py
import os
cwd1 = os.getcwd()
# can another module change the CWD here?
cwd2 = os.getcwd()
assert cwd1 == cwd2
```

I need to know if the `CWD` would stay the same in all situations with code like the example, or if I have to check, as rare as it may be, due to a race condition.

In other words, is that code thread-safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The working directory is owned by the process that starts the threads, so yes a thread can change the cwd and it will effect all threads in the process. For example this fails with an assertion error for me:

```
import threading
import time
import os


def test2():
    time.sleep(2)
    os.chdir('../')


def test1():
    cwd1 = os.getcwd()
    time.sleep(3)
    cwd2 = os.getcwd()
    assert cwd1 == cwd2


t1 = threading.Thread(target=test1)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=test2)
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

**Edit based on comments**

Using these functions you can see it's not deterministic — it sometimes fails, sometimes doesn't. But, importantly, it sometimes fails:

```
def test2():
    os.chdir('../')


def test1():
    cwd1 = os.getcwd()
    cwd2 = os.getcwd()
    try:
        assert cwd1 == cwd2
    except AssertionError:
        print("failed", cwd1, cwd2)
        return
```

In fact, it will often even fail with:

```
 assert os.getcwd() == os.getcwd()
```

Demonstrating that your thread can be suspended even within a single line.

Comment: Thanks, but that includes time.sleep(). I would like to know if somehow another thread can take over and change the CWD without any explicit sleep function, or similar, in my code. The only thing I would put between the 2 os.getcwd() would be a simple "if" statement.

Comment: Threads don't take over … the OS and Python switches context between threads in a way that your module has little over. This means that if there is something accessible and mutable by more than one running thread, you can have race conditions. The sleep just makes this deterministic for example purposes.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce your results and get it to fail with the updated functions (without sleep).

Comment: @CarlosGil you may not reproduce it because you are both working with different  processors, different os-s,  different levels of python.    you are getting good advice.  you should NEVER assume that in a multithreaded program  that you will not get interrupted.   you can use semaphores, etc if you must have ability to block the other threads from interferring.  You need to use good multithread principles always.

Comment: @LhasaDad thanks. Yours also sounds like great advice. To be clear, my module itself is not multithreaded in any way, but in case it's imported by another one that is, I guess it's worth assuming that the CWD might change while my function is being called and better make it safe now that I still know how it works.

Comment: @CarlosGil Just a thought.  relying on CWD in your module might be something to consider avoiding.  maybe it needs to be a passed parameter or configuration file option?  depends on if it would be allowed to change for different calls to your module.

Comment: @LhasaDad, appreciate it, but the module is all about paths and deals with cases not handled in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code demonstrating that when a thread changes the current working directory it is reflected in the other threads within the same process. We use a `threading.Event` instance that is set when the current working directory has been changed. This is more deterministic than sleeping:

```py
import threading
import os


def test2(lock):
    os.chdir('../')
    print('test2 cwd:', os.getcwd())
    cwd_event.set()


def test1(cwd_event):
    cwd_event.wait()
    print('test1 cwd:', os.getcwd())


print('Main thread initial cwd:', os.getcwd())
cwd_event = threading.Event()
t1 = threading.Thread(target=test1, args=(cwd_event,))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=test2, args=(cwd_event,))
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
print('Main thread final cwd:', os.getcwd())
```

Prints:

```None
Main thread initial cwd: C:\Booboo\test
test2 cwd: C:\Booboo
test1 cwd: C:\Booboo
Main thread final cwd: C:\Booboo
```

**How to Guarantee That Two Successive Calls to `getcwd` Return the Same Values**

```py
import threading
import os


def test2(cwd_event):
    with lock:
        os.chdir('../')


def test1(lock):
    with lock:
        # Guranteed that both calls will return the same value:
        print('test1 cwd:', os.getcwd())
        print('test1 cwd:', os.getcwd())


lock = threading.Lock()
t1 = threading.Thread(target=test1, args=(lock,))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=test2, args=(lock,))
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if my question was well-written or clear. If the 2 calls to os.getcwd() are on the same function, and that function has no multi-threading/sleep/wait functionality, and another module imports that function, can the thread be somehow suspended (by the interpreter or module that imports the function) between the 2 calls to os.getcwd()?

Comment: @CarlosGil Your previous comment is not clear either. Importing a function does not result in *calling* the function. When you say "suspended", do you mean the underlying platform (e.g. Windows) suspends the thread in order to dispatch some other process or thread? If so, that is always possible because a Python program has no control over the dispatching done by the underlying operating system. I interpreted your post as wanting know if one thread in a process changes directories is that reflected to the other threads within the process. And that is what I addressed in my answer.

Comment: And yes, between the two calls to `os.getcwd()`, if you have another thread within the same process changing directories at arbitrary times, you will find the the second call yields different results. If you create a `threading.Lock` and changing directories is done only after first acquiring the lock and the thread that is doing two successive calls to `getcwd` does so only after acquiring the lock, then you can be assured that you will get the same results. See update to answer.

Comment: @Booboo you need to edit your code.  the arg name in test2 is wrong,  should be lock in the def.

Comment: @Booboo, yes, perhaps I should have said that the other module that would import my function would call it. About your question: **"do you mean the underlying platform (e.g. Windows) suspends the thread in order to dispatch some other process or thread?"** Not another process, as the CWD would be per process, right? Your following comment is very clear that I should consider that the CWD might change between my calls to `os.getcwd()`. Although the solution for my module wouldn't be using locks, just parsing the string for any case.